# How to press enter and click for the same result using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my example code:

```
 $('#btnSave').click(function(){
  alert('hello');
 }
```

I also want to press enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btnSave').keypress(function (e) {
 var keyCode = e.which;
 if(keyCode == 13)  // enter key code
  {
    //place your code here
  }
});
```